Create local Windows 10 user and programmatically answer the privacy/advertising questions
I'm looking to create a local Windows 10 user via PowerShell or the commandline, and then finalize the 'account setup' programmatically.
If I currently create a new user User1 via New-LocalUser, and I manually sign in as User1 then I first get a 'Welcome, we're getting everything ready for you' screen and then I need to answer questions about using online speech recognition, location data, inking & typing, diagnostic data and advertising ID.
I would like to programmatically provide the answers to those questions and finalize the account setup, so that when User1 actually signs in, the questions no longer appear.
I've already found how to partially initialize the user profile by running 'Start-Process cmd /c' as User1 with -LoadUserProfile: this creates the user profile folder in C:\Users, but it doesn't remove the questions at first manual sign in.
